# c++ Passing vector of HIGH & LOW in arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I have an arduino which is listening through 6 separate input Pins for a specific combination of HIGH and LOW. I planned to separate out the listening from the pins as I would be calling the pins regularly based on additional functions. Code below outlines what I have setup thus far

```
const int InPins[6] = {3,4,5,6,7,8}; 
int *PinsReadOut[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
CntlLP = -1;

void setup() {
     Serial.begin(115200);
     for (int ii = 0, ii > 6, ii++) {
         pinMode(InPins[ii],INPUT)
     }
}

void loop(){
    switch(CntlLP)
         case -1:
            Serial.println("Waiting for Command");
            while (Serial.available()==0){}
            CntlLP=Serial.parseInt();
            break;
         case 1:
            ReadPins(PinsReadOut[6]);
            CntlLP = -1;
            break;
         case 2:
            if (PinsReadOut[0] == 1) && (PinsReadOut[1] == 1) {
                Serial.println("Received 1 & 2");
            }
            if (PinsReadOut[2] == 1) && (PinsReadOut[3] == 1) {
                Serial.println("Received 3 & 4");
            }
            if (PinsReadOut[4] == 1) && (PinsReadOut[5] == 1) {
                Serial.println("Received 5 & 6");
            }
            CntlLP = -1;
            break;
}

void ReadPins(int PinsReadOut[6]) {
     for (int ii = 0, ii > 6, ii++) {
         PinsReadOut[0] = digitalRead(InPins[ii])
     }
}
```

This code throws the following Error

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
```

I thought that maybe changing the if statement to == HIGH but it results in a different error

```
            if (PinsReadOut[0] == HIGH) && (PinsReadOut[1] == HIGH) {
                Serial.println("Received 1 & 2");
            }
```

Results in this error

```
 #define HIGH 0x1
```

Edit: Update for question
I was running into this error. which is why I used the *. I tried to follow the comments in the [arduino form](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=103681.0) to fix this error.

```
warning: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Why do you have a pointer to array `PinsReadOut`?  That's the source of your warning.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It is actually **array of pointers** not pointer to array

Comment: @bartop Pardon, you're right of course.

Comment: I tried this ended up with a different error. After going through google, I found that many people mentioned in order to pass a vector between functions. I should use pointers. Guess I'm using it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to make it work

I suggest You use array of ints instead of arrays of pointers to ints. That is the source of warning. So change this:

```
int *PinsReadOut[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

To this:

```
int PinsReadOut[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Also You are passing the array in a wrong way here:

```
ReadPins(PinsReadOut[6]);
```

You should change it to:

```
ReadPins(PinsReadOut);
```

#### Why it did not work

Well first of all - as the warning was telling You - You were trying to compare `int *` with `int` which is not allowed without `-fpermissive` compiler option. So instead of storing pointers in the array I suggested storing int values.

Secondly, instead of passing array to function taking array, You were trying to pass a specific value from this array, a value at position 7. Because in the context of function call `array[6]` means - value at the position 7 of the array (which is by the way out of bounds of array and causes undefined behaviour) because arrays in C(++) are 0-based.

Comment: First thing I tried but I ended up with this error. warning: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive].

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf Extended my answer. Hopefuly now it helps more

Comment: That worked without any error. thanks. My big question now though is why??

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf Added a bit of explanation. Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems with your code:

```
for (int ii = 0, ii > 6, ii++) {
    pinMode(InPins[ii],INPUT)
}
```

You probably wanted:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 6; ii++) {
    pinMode(InPins[ii],INPUT);
}
```

Note the use of `;` and `<`

Same here:

```
for (int ii = 0, ii > 6, ii++) {
   PinsReadOut[0] = digitalRead(InPins[ii])
}
```

You probably want:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 6; ii++) {
    PinsReadOut[ii] = digitalRead(InPins[ii]);
}
```

Note the use of `;`, `<` and `ii` for `PinsReadOut`

Of course the latter only possible if you declare `PinsReadOut` as an array of `ints` rather than an array of pointers to `ints`, i.e.

```
int *PinsReadOut[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Should be:

```
int PinsReadOut[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

And consequent call to ReadPins therefore should be:

```
ReadPins(PinsReadOut);
```